# Attaching CSV to ServiceNow Incident Record using Ansible

Tags: rest, ansible, servicenow

New to Ansible but looking for how to attach CSV to an Incident Record. I think most parts are right but do not know how to set the path to the file.

```yaml
- name: Attach CSV to record
    uri:
        url: "https://devvvvv.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=incident&table_sys_id={{ sysid }}&file_name=ticketCSV.csv"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ sn_username }}"
        password:  "{{ sn_password }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        headers:
            Content-Type: "application/json"
            Accept: "application/json"
        return_content: yes
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_AttachmentAPI-POSTmultipart.html) it talks about response header for location, where do I put this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the below worked for me:

```yml
  url: "{{ SN_HOST }}api/now/attachment/upload" 
  user: "{{ SN_USERNAME }}"
  password: "{{ SN_PASSWORD }}"
  method: POST
  return_content: true
  validate_certs: false
  force_basic_auth: no
  status_code: 201
  body_format: form-multipart
  headers:
      Accept: 'application/json'
      Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data'
  body:
    table_name:
        content: incident
    table_sys_id:
        content: " {{ new_incident['json']['result']['sys_id'] }} "
    uploadFile:
        filename: "../../win_playbooks/reports/{{ csv_filename }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

"Response header" is the response you get from SNOW, after you uploaded a file. SNOW then tells you the URL of the uploaded file.

For uploading a file via ansible you can check their documentation, especially the "src" tag: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am currently restricted to using 2.3.5 version so unable to use src, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: According to this https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/33689 you can use ``body: "{{ lookup('file', 'foo.json') }}``

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the code below which I've used

```yaml
 - name: Attach evidence to change record
   delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
   uri:
    url: "{{ snow_api }}/now/attachment/file?table_name=change_request&table_sys_id={{ change_created.json.result.sys_id }}&file_name=patches_on_test.txt"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json,version=2"
      Authorization: "Basic {{ credential }}"
    body: "{{ yum_history_info.stdout }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
    timeout: 120
    status_code: 200,202,201
   failed_when: false
   register: doc_upload
```